How to Programmatically Activate a Pseudo-Class on an Element?
Question: Is there any way to programmatically activate pseudo-classes such as :hover, :active, :focus, etc., in JavaScript or React? If so, how can this be done without modifying the original definitions of the pseudo-classes in CSS?
What I've Tried: I attempted to use mouse events like mouseover through dispatchEvent, but this did not work.
const buttonRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const button = buttonRef.current;
  const event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
  button.dispatchEvent(event);
}, []);

I aim to force the pseudo elements on multiple elements simultaneously, such that they remain with the style applied until I deactivate it.
Thanks in advance for your time! :)

I'm 99% sure you can't. Instead, have a class that applies the same styles that your :hover rule applies.

Chrome is able to do this when you open the inspector. Most probably there's a way

@Rhuan - There are lots of things devtools can do that there's no API for in normal code on a page.
